# Is it possible to record and repeat user actions in WebBrowserControl (Windows Forms)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, screen-scraping, webbrowser-control

I want to be able to use the .NET WebBrowserControl to record and repeat user actions to automate the collection and retrieval of text from web pages for a data extraction tool that I'm building, but am unsure about how to best approach this.

I specifically want to use the .NET WebBrowserControl as it can be embedded in a .NET form and also used within a server side process without a UI. I'm aware that there are other means of recording and repeating user actions such as Selenium, but for now I am interested in a solution around the web browser control (just to keep answers focused).

Actions to be recorded are those such as button clicks, drop down list selection, link clicks etc.

Potential solutions I have looked at so far:

(Please correct me if my notes based on brief evaluations are wrong)

iMacro (doesn't appear to have a component that can be used within a project, to record user actions, rather the GUI has to be used).

WaitN - Good for programmatic play back - but no recording facility that can be hooked up to the web browser control?

I'm presuming this is possible as services like Mozenda appear to make use of the WebBrowserControl, or some IE like version based on mshtml.dll.

Are there any other options I can look at?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

yap, as in Mozenda ,when user create any action like goto mainpage>click on images>download image etc... the XPath is recorded with the each page url into XML file.  So, use self learning algorithm to implement such kind of XML better way than mozenda.

i have developed one application using [JSOUP](http://www.jsoup.org/) and Regular Expression Parsing  works same as mozenda do. i created the configuration file which contains the XPath of all the items you want . Which works great for me.

Hope this helps,